# How can you programmatically emulate inertia scroll in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm currently using the following code to send scroll events based on user gesture:

```
let event = CGEvent(
            scrollWheelEvent2Source: nil,
            units: .pixel,
            wheelCount: 1,
            wheel1: delta,
            wheel2: 0,
            wheel3: 0)
        guard let scrollEvent = event else { return }
        scrollEvent.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

But how can you add some inertia (or momentum) afterwards? So that it works the same as scrolling with trackpad: after user finishes gesture, continue scrolling with decelerating velocity based on user's gesture velocity.

Comment: Apple notoriously locks down their scrolling APIs, so it only works with their trackpads (and absolutely shit-tier garbage) mouse. It's why no third-party mouse has smooth scrolling like the Magic Mouse. You'd probably have to reverse engineer private APIs to get the job done, but it probably won't be easy.

Comment: I know that it must be possible somehow, as I saw this functionality in a few apps. Do you think they implemented it programmatically, for example by setting a periodic timer and adding some decelerating curve?

Comment: Is this inertial scrolling something you're trying to implement in your own app, or is this something you're trying to apply system-wide? (i.e. are you writing a mouse driver?)

Comment: I think it's closer to the latter, I want to apply it system-wide